# Where can I find documentation for 'Visual Studio Notification Window'?

Tags: notifications, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

My team is developing a visual studio extension.

We are seeking to add push notifications to update users of updates to the extension. From my own research, I've been able to find out that notifications should show up in 'Visual Studio Notification Window', but I'm having trouble finding more documentation. Where can I learn more about notification support for VS extensions?

We want to add notifications about updates to our extension here:

[image: we want to add notifications about updates to our extension here:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've been able to find out that notifications should show up in
>   'Visual Studio Notification Window', but I'm having trouble finding
>   more documentation. Where can I learn more about notification support
>   for VS extensions?
>
> We want to add notifications about updates to our extension here.

I think you cannot get the notification Api in Visual Studio 2019. Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/notifications-and-progress-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#BKMK_VSNotificationsToolWindow):

***The Notifications window is not currently extensible.***

Microsoft does not open an extended interface to the `notification window`.